# How do you make tables with previously stored strings?

Tags: python

So the question basically gives me 19 DNA sequences and wants me to makea basic text table. The first column has to be the sequence ID, the second column the length of the sequence, the third is the number of "A"'s, 4th is "G"'s, 5th is "C", 6th is "T", 7th is %GC, 8th is whether or not it has "TGA" in the sequence. Then I get all these values and write a table to "dna_stats.txt"

Here is my code:

```
fh = open("dna.fasta","r")
Acount = 0
Ccount = 0
Gcount = 0
Tcount = 0
seq=0
alllines = fh.readlines()
for line in alllines:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        seq+=1
        continue
    Acount+=line.count("A")
    Ccount+=line.count("C")
    Gcount+=line.count("G")
    Tcount+=line.count("T")
    genomeSize=Acount+Gcount+Ccount+Tcount
    percentGC=(Gcount+Ccount)*100.00/genomeSize
    print "sequence", seq
    print "Length of Sequence",len(line)
    print Acount,Ccount,Gcount,Tcount
    print "Percent of GC","%.2f"%(percentGC)
    if "TGA" in line:
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
    fh2 = open("dna_stats.txt","w")
    for line in alllines:
        splitlines = line.split()
        lenstr=str(len(line))
        seqstr = str(seq)
        fh2.write(seqstr+"\t"+lenstr+"\n")
```

I found that you have to convert the variables into strings. I have all of the values calculated correctly when I print them out in the terminal. However, I keep getting only 19 for the first column, when it should go 1,2,3,4,5,etc. to represent all of the sequences. I tried it with the other variables and it just got the total amounts of the whole file. I started trying to make the table but have not finished it.

So my biggest issue is that I don't know how to get the values for the variables for each specific line.

I am new to python and programming in general so any tips or tricks or anything at all will really help.

I am using python version 2.7

Comment: Is a single DNA sequence all on one line starting with `>`. Or does a single DNA sequence go accross accross multiple lines?

Comment: There is a single DNA sequence for each line. They are all different.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your biggest issue:

```
for line in alllines: #1
    ...
    fh2 = open("dna_stats.txt","w")
    for line in alllines: #2
        ....
```

Indentation matters.  This says "for every line (#1), open a file and then loop over *every* line again(#2)..."

De-indent those things.

Answer (score 0):

This puts the info in a dictionary as you go and allows for DNA sequences to go over multiple lines

```
from __future__ import division # ensure things like 1/2 is 0.5 rather than 0
from collections import defaultdict

fh = open("dna.fasta","r")
alllines = fh.readlines()


fh2 = open("dna_stats.txt","w")
seq=0
data = dict()
for line in alllines:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        seq+=1
        data[seq]=defaultdict(int) #default value will be zero if key is not present hence we can do +=1 without originally initializing to zero        
        data[seq]['seq']=seq
        previous_line_end = "" #TGA might be split accross line
        continue

    data[seq]['Acount']+=line.count("A")
    data[seq]['Ccount']+=line.count("C")
    data[seq]['Gcount']+=line.count("G")
    data[seq]['Tcount']+=line.count("T")
    data[seq]['genomeSize']+=data[seq]['Acount']+data[seq]['Gcount']+data[seq]['Ccount']+data[seq]['Tcount']

    line_over = previous_line_end + line[:3]        
    data[seq]['hasTGA']= data[seq]['hasTGA'] or ("TGA" in line) or (TGA in line_over)
    previous_line_end = str.strip(line[-4:]) #save previous_line_end for next line removing new line character.


for seq in data.keys():    
    data[seq]['percentGC']=(data[seq]['Gcount']+data[seq]['Ccount'])*100.00/data[seq]['genomeSize']    
    s = '%(seq)d, %(genomeSize)d, %(Acount)d, %(Ccount)d, %(Tcount)d, %(Tcount)d, %(percentGC).2f, %(hasTGA)s'
    fh2.write(s % data[seq])

fh.close()    
fh2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would this work for python 2.7? Sorry I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: Which part throws an error in python2.7.  (note I changed `future` to `__future__` in my first line.) If you edit your question to give a sample of your data file such as 2 or 3 DNA sequences I can test it as I use Python2.7 too (just truncate the DNA sequences if they are really long).